# NoneClass type as a product of a function

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I'm writing a simple function operating string data:

```
def load_utterance(raw_data_par, TCrun):
    ready_to_eat = []
    for id, utterance in enumerate(raw_data_par):
        if len(ready_to_eat) < TCruns:
            ready_to_eat.append(utterance)
            raw_data_par.pop(id)
        else:
            return ready_to_eat
```

I initiate the function:

```
raw_data_utterance = load_utterance(raw_data, TCruns)
```

And later on attempt to iterate through the created list. However an error pops up of raw_data_utterance being an object of a NoneType class. I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake. Could someone please point me in the general direction?
Thank you so much!

Comment: What if the ```if``` statement was True all the time? There is no return statement

Comment: Is `raw_data_par` a list? You could just skip the loop and write `return raw_data_par[:TCrun]`. (Assuming you don't actually want to modify `raw_data_par` in the process.)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is finishing before `ready_to_eat` is long enough. It returns nothing, which means it will return `None`.

Also, the `pop()` call may not be a good idea. It will remove the element you're currently on, moving all subsequent values down one index. On the next iteration of your loop, you'll get the value from the next *index* of the list, missing one value: your loop will only see every other value from `raw_data_par`.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just return `ready_to_eat` at the end, you don't need the `else`:

```py
def load_utterance(raw_data_par, TCrun):
    ready_to_eat = []
    for id, utterance in enumerate(raw_data_par):
        if len(ready_to_eat) < TCruns:
            ready_to_eat.append(utterance)
            raw_data_par.pop(id)
    
    return ready_to_eat
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in

```
def load_utterance(raw_data_par, TCrun):
    ready_to_eat = []
    for id, utterance in enumerate(raw_data_par):
        if len(ready_to_eat) < TCruns:
            ready_to_eat.append(utterance)
            raw_data_par.pop(id)
        else:
            return ready_to_eat
```

this code is that there is no `return` statement in the `if` block. So if all the conditions for `if` become True, then it will execute whatever code is below. It will not even touch `else`. Once it has iterated over the elements, the function ends, and there is no `return` statement.

Hence, the returned value is `None` or *nothing*